# cake php distinct date_format

Tags: distinct, cakephp-3.0, date-format

Please I need some help with `cakephp3` mysql distinct.

My desire result in SQL:

```
select distinct(date_format(torokuDate,'%Y')) as year 
from kani_tbl 
where torokuDate >= '2000-01-01' 
order by torokuDate ASC 
limit 1;
```

But I get the wrong result:

```
SELECT (date_format((torokuDate), '%Y')) AS `year` 
FROM kani_tbl 
WHERE torokuDate > :c0 
GROUP BY torokuDate  
ORDER BY torokuDate ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

My model src:

```
$query = $this->find(); 
$time = $query->func()->date_format([ 
        'torokuDate' => 'identifier', 
        "'%Y'" => 'literal' 
]); 

$yearList = $query->select(['year' => $time]) 
            ->distinct('torokuDate') 
            ->from('kani_tbl ') 
            ->order(['torokuDate' => 'ASC']) 
            ->where(['torokuDate >' => '2000-01-01']) 
            ->limit(1); 
//              ->hydrate(false) 
//              ->toArray(); 
var_dump($yearList);
```

Please help me to add distinct field in the MySQL command.

Answer (score 0):

As your expected query, you need to distinct result of date_format(torokuDate, '%Y'), not the 'torokuDate' field. So your code should be like this:

```
$yearList = $query->select(['year' => $time]) 
        ->distinct()
        ->from('kani_tbl ') 
        ->order(['torokuDate' => 'ASC']) 
        ->where(['torokuDate >' => '2000-01-01']) 
        ->limit(1);
```

How to use distinct method: https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_distinct

Comment: Thanks for your help